# "x is not a class or namespace name" when trying to use functions between namespaces

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces

I am new to C++ and am currently trying to implement namespaces.

Here, you can see, I have a namespace, `GameEngine_CORE`, where all the behind-the-scenes work is done. I have the namespace `SandBox`, which is where the user actually would write their game.

I need `SandBox` to be able to access some of the variables in `GameEngine_CORE`, which seems to work fine (I have put a list of `using GameEngine_CORE::...` to save the user's time).

However, I also need `GameEngine_CORE` to be able to call the `start()` and `update()` function in `SandBox`, but upon compilation I get an error every time I try and call something from `SandBox`, eg: `SandBox::start();`

> 'SandBox' is not a class or namespace name

I am coding in Visual Studio, and compiling in Debug mode for Windows x64.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "SDL.h"
#undef main
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h> // Temp

#include "Vec2.h"
#include "Log.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include "Boundary.h"
#include "Ray.h"
#include "Particle.h"
#include "Polygon.h"
#include "Path.h"
#include "Circle.h"

namespace GameEngine_CORE {
    // Renderer
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Window* window;
    bool isRunning;
    bool fullscreen;
    // Mouse
    int mouseX;
    int mouseY;
    Uint32 mouse;
    // Keyboard
    Vec2 arrowInp;
    // Collision Stack
    std::vector<Boundary> collisionStack;
    // Log
    Log logger;
    // Physics
    Time timer;
    Time clockTime;
    float deltaTime;
    Vec2 gravity = Vec2(0, -9.8f);

    void handleEvents();
    void render();
    void createWindow();
    void destroyWindow();

    // For the SandBox Program
    void SandBox::start();
    void SandBox::update();

    int main() { // Entry Point
        double m_LastClock = 0.0;
        clockTime.StartTimer(); // Start Counter

        SandBox::start(); // For user
        while (isRunning) {
            double m_CurrentClock;
            m_CurrentClock = clockTime.GetTimer(); // Get Counter
            deltaTime = (float)(m_CurrentClock - m_LastClock);
            if (deltaTime > 0.15f) {
                deltaTime = 0.15f;
            }
            handleEvents();
            render();

            m_LastClock = m_CurrentClock;
        }

        destroyWindow();

        return 0;
    }

    // Initialise the window to draw to
    void createWindow() {
        // Set window size and type
        fullscreen = true;
        Uint32 flags = 0;
        flags = SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;
        if (fullscreen) {
            flags = flags | SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED;
        }
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0) {
            logger.Message("Subsystems Initialised");

            window = SDL_CreateWindow("2D Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 300, 300, flags);
            if (window) {
                logger.Message("Window Created");
                // Minimum window size
                SDL_SetWindowMinimumSize(window, 1000, 1000);
            }
            // Create Renderer for window
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
            if (renderer) {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 121, 121, 121, 255);
                logger.Message("Renderer Created");
                // Set how to blend alphas and colours
                SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
                isRunning = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void destroyWindow() {
        // Frees memory associated with renderer and window
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);  //error here
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    // Handles SDL events
    void handleEvents() {
        // Check for quit
        SDL_Event event;
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);

        // Check we have latest inputs
        SDL_PumpEvents();

        // Reset inputs
        arrowInp.x = 0; arrowInp.y = 0;

        // If we get quit event, stop running and free up memory
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            isRunning = false;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_LEFT: arrowInp.x = -1; break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT: arrowInp.x = 1; break;
            }
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_UP: arrowInp.y = -1; break;
            case SDLK_DOWN: arrowInp.y = 1; break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }


    }

    // Render Function
    void render() {
        // Set back ground colour and clear renderer every frame
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SandBox::update();

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); // Draw to the screen
    }
}

using GameEngine_CORE::createWindow;
using GameEngine_CORE::deltaTime;
using GameEngine_CORE::mouse;
using GameEngine_CORE::mouseX;
using GameEngine_CORE::mouseY;
using GameEngine_CORE::renderer;
using GameEngine_CORE::arrowInp;
using GameEngine_CORE::collisionStack;

namespace SandBox { // Where the user of the engine would write code
    // Drawing Vars
    Particle particle = Particle(50, 359.99f, Vec2(900, 700));
    Boundary boundaries[] = { Boundary(Vec2(800, 0), Vec2(800, 1000)), Boundary(Vec2(300, 300), Vec2(400, 700)), Boundary(Vec2(300, 700), Vec2(800, 800)) };
    GameEngine::Polygon square = GameEngine::Polygon(Vec2(800, 400), 45, Vec2(400, 200), 4);
    GameEngine::Polygon poly1 = GameEngine::Polygon(Vec2(200, 400), Vec2(200, 200), 6);
    GameEngine::Polygon ellipse = GameEngine::Polygon(Vec2(1200, 600), Vec2(200, 400), 64);
    Path path = Path(Vec2(500, 100));
    Circle circle = Circle(100, Vec2(800, 500));

    GameEngine::Polygon player = GameEngine::Polygon(Vec2(700, 400), 0, Vec2(60, 60), 16);
    float moveSpeed;
    Vec2 velocity;

    float rotator = 0;

    // Functions
    static void collision();

    static void start() {   // Called when the program starts
        createWindow();

        moveSpeed = 1000.0f;

        path.addPoints(std::vector<Vec2> { Vec2(200, 100), Vec2(200, 800), Vec2(350, 800), Vec2(700, 650), Vec2(400, 400), Vec2(200, 100)});
    }


    static void update() { // Repeats every frame
        printf("%f secs \n", deltaTime);
        // Get the mouse' current state
        mouse = SDL_GetMouseState(&mouseX, &mouseY);
        particle.setPos(Vec2((float)mouseX, (float)mouseY));

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);      // Draw Boundaries

        rotator += 0.01f;
        poly1.setRot(rotator);

        // Player
        player.Show(renderer);

        square.Show(renderer);
        poly1.Show(renderer);
        ellipse.Show(renderer);
        path.Show(renderer);

        collision();
    }

    static void collision() {
        // Clears stack
        collisionStack.clear();

        // Adds colliders to stack
        square.makeCollider(collisionStack);
        poly1.makeCollider(collisionStack);
        ellipse.makeCollider(collisionStack);
        path.makeCollider(collisionStack);
        player.makeCollider(collisionStack);

        // Draw Particles
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 0, 100);
        particle.collide(renderer, collisionStack);
    }

    static void movement() {
        Vec2 velocity = arrowInp * moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

I don't imagine anyone needs to see the header files, but I can provide them if requested. I also declare my `start()` and `update()` functions in `GameEngine_CORE`, which I'm not sure is correct, however I was getting complaints from Visual Studio that it could not find the function definitions otherwise.

Comment: Is the code you present just 1 header file or do you have multiple header files involved? If the latter do these header files include each other forming a loop?

Comment: A [mre] would help us to see the problem

Comment: The best way to find a problem like this is to back up the program and then take an axe to it. Play divide and conquer until you have isolated the problem in a smaller chunk of code. If you still can't solve the when it's got a lot less noise to hide in, that's when you ask Stack Overflow. Right now all I can really say is "Can't reproduce. Too many unrelated compiler errors."

Comment: Could be as simple as `Sandbox` is declared after the code using it. Hard to tell if the layout here in the question is really representative of the real code.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes I do include quite a few header files, but as far as I can tell there are no loops being made.

Comment: @user4581301 I moved the 'SandBox' namespace above the 'GameEngine_CORE' and sure enough it is now instead complaining that 'GameEngine_CORE' is not a class or namespace name. Do I need to declare a namespace or something so it knows it's there? I'm also sorry I don't have a minimal reproduceable example as Ted Lyngmo was asking, I'm trying to figure out what that would look like.

Comment: Moving the two namespaces around and watching the error switch suggests you have a circular dependency somewhere. Save everything, back it up, and then start hacking off bits you think are unrelated until you wind up with something stupid like two nearly empty namespaces and a `main` function. If you can get to that point without spotting the mistake, it's a sneaky son of a gun.

Comment: Hey, is `main` really inside `GameEngine_CORE`? Linker's not gonna like that, Yogi.

Comment: and @drescherjm is right. If you've implemented everything inside the headers, it's going to be very hard to untangle circular dependencies.. This is one of the reasons the real meat-and-potatoes are usually done in separate files. A cpp file can include two fully defined headers that cannot include each other. If you define both sides of a circular dependency and later implement after both sides are completely declared there is no more fighting over which piece has to come first.

Comment: @user4581301 I think I fixed it! I did what you said and backed it up and then started hacking out bits of the code, I also then moved main out of 'GameEngine_CORE' because I had also seen a linker error at some point down the road. Then after moving the namespaces before main it all seems to compile and link fine. It seemed that the issue was to do with me calling the start and update functions (from 'SandBox') inside 'GameEngine_CORE' was a nono. Thanks a lot for the help! (I will also look into using multiple cpp files)